# How to implement zoom-in/zoom-out effect on a cocos2d sprite image?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing module where-in I pick the image from photo library and put into a sprite. I want to implement zoom-in/zoom-out kind of effect for a sprite image, same like camera album images zoom in/out effect. Could someone please guide me how do i implement it?

I see somewhere is that, I have to detect two touch events in `ccTouchBegan` and then adjust the sprite's scale size to up or down based on the distance of two fingers touch event values.

Could someone please tell me:

- How do i detect two fingers touch values in `ccTouchBegan`?
- How to allow to touch and zoom-in/out of sprite image by user? Please give me samples. I tried already some stuff from [this URL](http://groups.google.com/group/cocos2d-iphone-discuss/browse_thread/thread/61808fd6b578e5e1?hide_quotes=no&utoken=9AdrAzkAAABFNHPPibbeOSHIuKOkxTWQ066onEraO3W2r08xbUjNmAwT6_SsyC2n0d69MF_vYn77vPb7MuI5eIWgjrXT32Kd), but doesn't work for my requirement.

Thank you.

Comment: Any help please? I haven't succeeded yet on this with proper code?

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to use gesture recognizer for zooming:

```
    // on initializing your scene:
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer* PinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector (zoom:)];
    [[[Director sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer: PinchGesture];
...
/// zoom callback:
-(void) zoom: (UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
    if (([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) || ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged))
        yourSprite.scale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) First step you need create two variables.

```
BOOL canPinch; 
float oldScale;
```

2) Use the brigadir's :) answer and add this in your init method

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector (zoom:)];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
```

3)

```
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{     
    NSArray* allTouches = [[event allTouches] allObjects];
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];;

    CGRect particularSpriteRect = CGRectMake(spriteToZoom.position.x-[spriteToZoom boundingBox].size.width/2, spriteToZoom.position.y-[spriteToZoom boundingBox].size.height/2, [spriteToZoom boundingBox].size.width, [spriteToZoom boundingBox].size.height);

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(particularSpriteRect, location)) 
    {  
        if ([allTouches count] == 2) 
        {     
            canPinch = YES; 
            return;
        }   
        else if ([allTouches count] == 1)
        {  
            CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

            CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
            oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
            oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];

            CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldTouchLocation);    
            [self panForTranslation:translation]; 
        }

    }
    canPinch = NO;
}

- (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation 
{     
    CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(spriteToZoom.position, translation);
    spriteToZoom.position = newPos; 
}

- (void)zoom: (UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
    if (canPinch) 
    {
        if (([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) || ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged))
        {       
            spriteToZoom.scale = oldScale + [gestureRecognizer scale]-(oldScale != 0 ? 1 : 0);  
        }
        if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        { 
            oldScale = spriteToZoom.scale; 
        } 
    } 
}
```